# Jquery mobile image upload ajax - Help me gell the code please

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am trying code to upload images with jquery mobile.
I have a working php script written to upload images.
I have a working jquery script that will display the upload on jquery mobile.

How do I "gell" the two scripts?

My full mobile page script as follow:

```
<head>
<title>jQM input file capture</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
```

```
<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <style>
        #preview {
            width: 80%; max-width: 300px;
        }
        #preview img {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .hiddenfile {
         width: 0px;
         height: 0px;
         overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
    <div data-role="header">
         <h3>Header</h3>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <button id="chooseFile">Choose file</button>
        <div class="hiddenfile">
          <input type="file"  data-clear-btn="false" name="image" accept="image/*" capture>
        </div>
        <div id="preview">
        </div>
        <ul id="info" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>

<script>
$('#page').on('pageinit', function(){
    $("#chooseFile").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("input[type=file]").trigger("click");
    });
    $("input[type=file]").change(function(){
        var file = $("input[type=file]")[0].files[0];            
        $("#preview").empty();
        displayAsImage3(file, "preview");

        $info = $("#info");
        $info.empty();
        if (file && file.name) {
            $info.append("<li>name:<span>" + file.name + "</span></li>");
        }
        if (file && file.type) {
            $info.append("<li>size:<span>" + file.type + " bytes</span></li>");
        }
        if (file && file.size) {
            $info.append("<li>size:<span>" + file.size + " bytes</span></li>");
        }
        if (file && file.lastModifiedDate) {
            $info.append("<li>lastModifiedDate:<span>" + file.lastModifiedDate + " bytes</span></li>");
        }
        $info.listview("refresh");
    });
});

function displayAsImage3(file, containerid) {
    if (typeof FileReader !== "undefined") {
        var container = document.getElementById(containerid),
            img = document.createElement("img"),
            reader;
        container.appendChild(img);
        reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function (theImg) {
            return function (evt) {
                theImg.src = evt.target.result;
            };
        }(img));
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}

</script>
```

Where can I now add an ajax call to the php file that will do the actual upload & Mysql Insert...

My ajax php file will look as follow:

```
<?
if (isset($_FILES['img1'])) {
  $change="";
  $imgNumb=1;
    $post['ad'] = $_POST['ad'];
    $post['user'] = $_POST['user'];
  define ("MAX_SIZE","4000");
          function getExtension($str) { // To get the image extention
            $i = strrpos($str,".");
            if (!$i) { return ""; }
            $l = strlen($str) - $i;
            $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
            return $ext;
            }
  $errors=0; // Set error as 0
do{
if($_FILES["img$imgNumb"]["tmp_name"]!=''){
    $image =$_FILES["img$imgNumb"]["name"];
    $uploadedfile = $_FILES["img$imgNumb"]['tmp_name'];
      if ($image){  
        $filename = stripslashes($_FILES["img$imgNumb"]['name']);
        $extension = getExtension($filename);
        $extension = strtolower($extension);
// Verify Image Extention
 if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif")){
            $change='Only jpg, gif and png images are allowed.';
            $errors=1;
        }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// IMAGE FILE SIZE START
if(($_FILES["img$imgNumb"]["size"] > 4000000)){
    $change='You have exceeded the size limit! Only Images up to 4Mb Max are allowed.';
    $errors=1;
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// IMAGE FILE SIZE END
        else{
 $size=filesize($_FILES["img$imgNumb"]['size']);
if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024){ // Check image size
    $change='You have exceeded the size limit! Only Images up to 2Mb Max are allowed.';
    $errors=1;
}
if($extension=="jpg" || $extension=="jpeg" ){
$uploadedfile = $_FILES["img$imgNumb"]['tmp_name'];
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);
}
else if($extension=="png"){
$uploadedfile = $_FILES["img$imgNumb"]['tmp_name'];
$src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);
}
else {
$src = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);
}
echo $scr;
list($width,$height)=getimagesize($uploadedfile);
if ($width < 300 AND $height < 300){ // Check image size
    $change='Sorry! ...but the image you are trying to upload is too small. Please upload an image which has a minimum size (either height or width) of 300px';
    $errors=1;
}
if($width < 400) {
$newheightX=$height;
$newwidthX=$width;
}
else {
$newwidthX=400;
$newheightX=($height/$width)*$newwidthX;
}
if($newheightX > 400) {
$newheight=400;
$newwidth=($newwidthX/$newheightX)*$newheight;
} else {
$newheight = $newheightX;
$newwidth = $newwidthX; } 
$tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 800
if($width >= 400) {
$newwidth8X=800;
$newheight8X=($height/$width)*$newwidth8X;
if($newheight8X > 600) {
$newheight88=600;
$newwidth88=($newwidth8X/$newheight8V)*$newheight88;
} else {
$newheight88 = $newheight8X;
$newwidth88 = $newwidth8X;
}
$pic800=1;
$tmp8=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth88,$newheight88);
}
else if($height >= 300) {
$newwidth8X=800;
$newheight8X=($height/$width)*$newwidth8X;
if($newheight8X > 600) {
$newheight88=600;
$newwidth88=($newwidth8X/$newheight8V)*$newheight88;
} else {
$newheight88 = $newheight8X;
$newwidth88 = $newwidth8X;
}
$pic800=1;
$tmp8=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth88,$newheight88);
}
else{
$pic800=0;
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$newwidth1=130;
$newheight1=($height/$width)*$newwidth1;
if($newheight1 > 130) {
$newheight11=130;
$newwidth11=($newwidth1/$newheight1)*$newheight11;
} else {
$newheight11 = $newheight1;
$newwidth11 = $newwidth1; }
$tmp1=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth11,$newheight11);
if ($imgNumb == 1){
$newwidth2=65;
$newheight2=($height/$width)*$newwidth2;
if($newheight2 > 65) {
$newheight22=65;
$newwidth22=($newwidth2/$newheight2)*$newheight22;
} else {
$newheight22 = $newheight2;
$newwidth22 = $newwidth2; }
$tmp2=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth22,$newheight22);
}
imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);
if($pic800==1){
imagecopyresampled($tmp8,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth88,$newheight88,$width,$height);
}
imagecopyresampled($tmp1,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth1,$newheight1,$width,$height);
if ($imgNumb == 1){
imagecopyresampled($tmp2,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth2,$newheight2,$width,$height);
}
/// SET IMAGE NAMES HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
//$image_name=time().'.'.$extension;
$Unique=microtime(); // We want unique names, right?
$image_name=md5($Unique).'.'.$extension;
$dbimgname=$imgNumb.'_'.$image_name;
if ($dbimgname==''){
    $change='You have exceeded the size limit! Only Images up to 4Mb Max are allowed.';
    $errors=1;
}
$filename = '../ad_images/'.$imgNumb.'_'.$image_name;
if($pic800==1){
$filename8 = '../ad_images/800/'.$imgNumb.'_'.$image_name;
}
$filename1 = '../ad_images/130/'.$imgNumb.'_'.$image_name;
if ($imgNumb == 1){
$filename2 = '../ad_images/65/'.$imgNumb.'_'.$image_name;
}
imagejpeg($tmp,$filename,85);
if($pic800==1){
imagejpeg($tmp8,$filename8,85);
}
imagejpeg($tmp1,$filename1,85);
if ($imgNumb == 1){
imagejpeg($tmp2,$filename2,85);
}
imagedestroy($src);
imagedestroy($tmp);
if($pic800==1){
imagedestroy($tmp8);
}
imagedestroy($tmp1);
if ($imgNumb == 1){
imagedestroy($tmp2);
}
}}
}
$imgNumb++;
} while($_FILES["img$imgNumb"][name]);
//If no errors registred, print the success message
 if(isset($_FILES['img1']) && !$errors && $dbimgname!=''){
    $change='<img src="../images/130/'.$dbimgname.'" border="0px" />';
//Get max pick order
$maxquery = mysql_query("select * from image WHERE  user = '$user' order by `picorder` DESC limit 1");
$maxrow = mysql_fetch_array($maxquery);
$result2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM image WHERE picorder='1' AND user='$user'");
if(mysql_num_rows($result2)== 0) {
$maxNum=1;
}
else {$maxNum = $maxrow['picorder'] +1;}
if($cat=='8' OR $sub=='841' OR $sub=='842'){
$setaprv='0';
}else {
$setaprv='1';
}
  $query = "INSERT INTO image(image, user, aproved) VALUES ('$dbimgname', '$user', '$setaprv')";
            mysql_query($query);
            $uperror = '';
}
//If error with upload
else if(isset($_FILES['img1']) && $errors){
$uperror = '<div style="Background: #FF0000;
font-weight:bold;
width: 100%;
color: white; 
  font-family:Verdana,Arial,sans-serif; 
  font-size: 10px; 
  text-align: left;">Error!!! '.$change.' - Try Again!</div>';
}
}
?>
```